# specifying source branch while triggering AWS CodeBuild from a CloudWatch event

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-codebuild

I have created a cloudwatch event which triggers a codebuild project when there is a push in the master branch of a codecommit repo. I am trying to build the project when there is a push in the "develop" branch. I can specify the source branch for triggering the build. However, codebuild is always building from the master branch.

I am looking for a way to send the source branch to codebuild when initiated by a cloudwatch event trigger.

This is my cloudwatch event.

[image]

Comment: have you considered letting codepipeline set all this up for you?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the answer is a yes, but the idea shouldn't be having one pipeline per CodeBuild project, I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 3):

It's of course a very old thread, but I found it when googling the same question, so maybe someone will find it useful:
To make CloudWatch trigger a build on the PR where you pushed, when specifying target chose “Input Transformer”. There in “input path” enter `{"source-version":"$.detail.sourceReference"}`.
In “Input Template” textbox enter `{"sourceVersion": <source-version>}`.
Worked for me.